# Certificate chain different between HTTPSURLconnection and Apache (System) DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x, sni

I am facing a weird issue wrto Apache HTTPS client. I am trying to connect to an external HTTPS website which has basic authentication turned on (SSL server authenticaion only). Here is the summary of my tests and conclusions.

- Use a either of Chrome/Firefox/IE to connect to the website ->  success
- Use `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` -> success
- Use either of `DefaultHttpClient` or `SystemDefaultHttpClient` -> failure

I tried to debug by enabling "javax.net.debug" to "ssl". I noticed that both the clients pick up the same trust store (default JDK trust store) and use the same protocol (TLSv1). 
However, the differences were here

I noticed that the following extension was returned by the JDK

> Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: websitehostname]

while the above extension was missing in the Apache web client debug log.

Also, one more difference I saw was in the certficate chain

The below response from JDK native

> *** Certificate chain
>   chain [0] = [
>   [
>     Version: V3
>     Subject: **CN=websitename**, OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13, OU=GT17702541, SERIALNUMBER=Q2La1fpFlFdNy4kUCIehYlMvw6bq64Ch
>     Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

while in apache client the following

> chain [0] = [ [   Version: V3   Subject: EMAILADDRESS=root@i4319,
>   **CN=i4319**, OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit, O=SomeOrganization, L=SomeCity,
>   ST=SomeState, C=--   Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID =
>   1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

and obviously I get the following exception with apache https client.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

Before I go back and redo my work to use the JDK native client, I would like to know what is happening.
Any insight on this behaviour would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not really have a clue (the SSLSocketFactory underlying Apache HTTP Client ultimately is the same as what the JDK uses for HTTPSURLConnection), but first thing that comes to mind could be Proxy settings, you should enable the "wire" debug and check if one client or the other goes through one...

Proxies are good at generating fake certificates when they do SSL Filtering.

Comment: If you are talking about the proxy in my network, then I have to say, I have never configured one (in browser, for example).

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching looks like this weird issue is because of lack of SNI support in Apache Client. Here is the JIRA that discusses the problem and possible solution here

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1119

and a possible work around here

https://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/SNISupport