# Use TLS 1.2 in mssql jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

Starting which version of mssql-jdbc- jre8 is TLS 1.2 supported? Is a special configuration needed to use TLS 1.2? or it works out of the box)MSSQL server is set up to accept only TLS 1.2 connections)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Starting which version of mssql-jdbc- jre8 is TLS 1.2 supported?

Java 8 supports TLS1.0 through TLS1.2, and TLS1.2 is the default; see [Transport Level Security (TLS) and Java](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/tls-and-java).  The MSSQL JDBC drivers will use the JVM's SSL libraries.

> Is a special configuration needed to use TLS 1.2?

No.  Not on the client side.

> or it works out of the box.

Yes.

> MSSQL server is set up to accept only TLS 1.2 connections?

That would depend on how the database server itself is configured.   According to ["TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server), SQL Server 2016 supports TLS 1.0 through 1.2, but you can configure it to disable versions that you don't want.

For the record TLS1.3 is available in Java 8 since 1.8.0u261; see [TLSv1.3 - is it available now in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437596).

Comment: you may need to add `trustServerCertificate=true;` at your connection url if you get handshake errors  `jdbc:sqlserver://DB-MyServer:1433;DatabaseName=mydb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;`

Comment: That is an orthogonal issue ... and probably a bad idea.  It is better to figure out *why* the server cert is being rejected, and fix the cause.