# Updating OpenJDK Version in an Older jboss/wildfly Docker Image

Tags: java, docker, jboss, tls1.3

For **TLSv1.3** support we need min Java 8u261-b12 version as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437596/tlsv1-3-is-it-available-now-in-java-8).

How can we update Open JDK version to **8u lastest** in an older Docker Image such as **jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final**?

Is there a best practice for that? My DockerFile starts like that:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download the jdk1.8.0_311 package an unzip it. With using COPY command I override the old JDK in the image with DockerFile, it worked!

**DockerFile**

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final

USER root
COPY JRE/* /usr/lib/jvm/java/
RUN chown -R root /usr/lib/jvm/java/
RUN chmod -R 775 /usr/lib/jvm/java/
```