# How to change the JavaVersion of Jboss/wildfly Dockerimage

Tags: java, docker, jboss, wildfly

I'm really new to Docker and wanted to setup a Wildfly-Container (v26) and deploying a .war-File to it.
The problem I've encountered is, that Wildfly is using [JDK11](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly/blob/master/Dockerfile) as base image.

My program was written in JDK17. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70517507/updating-openjdk-version-in-an-older-jboss-wildfly-docker-image) to change the JDK and the wildfly is running, but I have no idea if it worked. Is there any command or way to read out the used java version the docker image of wildfly is now using?

Sure I could 'just deploy' the war, but I have no access to the admin console. It looks like there is another problem I have to fix before.

Comment: Are you taking advantage of anything in Java 12+?  If not you can recompile as a Java 11 project.

Comment: Yeah I use some Stuff from newer JavaVersions. Therefore a recompile ist nothing, I can do.
I could get access to the admin console and as I thought, it seems like the wrong javaversion is running. I can't deploy the WAR due to an Error coming from a class which uses newer javaversion stuff.

Maybe I just set up m own image based on java17 and install wildfly on that.

Comment: Building your own makes the most sense then.  It shouldn't be too bad as you can use that container as a pattern.