# TLSv1.3 Unsupported Issues in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, ssl

We have a spring boot app with an embedded Tomcat server. I started getting protocol version errors recently which I think could be due to an update. These errors originally surfaced locally after a spring boot upgrade so that is probably related. We are still on Java 8.

I resolved this initially by adding -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 to my app startup.

However, whenever trying to call my app I now get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TLSv1.3
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.valueOf(ProtocolVersion.java:187)
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolList.convert(ProtocolList.java:84)
    ...
    at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

With postman I tried forcing this by excluding TLSv1.3, With curl I tried using `--tls-max 1.2` combined with tlsv1.2 but the same error still happens. How can I determine where v1.3 is being used and prevent it from happening?

Comment: Check your exact Java 8 version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437596/tlsv1-3-is-it-available-now-in-java-8