# How to make a request with HttpComponents (Java apache lib) changing Server Name Indication in TLS Handshake

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2, apache-httpcomponents

I have to make a request to a backend with TLS certificate and private key and in my troubleshooting I got error when using the same hostname in the Server Name Indication. See:

I got ERROR:

> openssl s_client -connect endpoint.com:443 -servername endpoint.com

I got SUCCESS:

```
openssl s_client -connect endpoint.com:443 -servername another_endpoint_name.com
```

But I can't find a way to change the server name indication in the `TLS Handshake` in the `Apache Lib.` Is it even possible?

Related question: [How to set SNI (Server Name Indication) in TLS Handshake using Apache HttpComponents Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788491/how-to-set-sni-server-name-indication-in-tls-handshake-using-apache-httpcompon)

Answer (score 0):

One can create a custom request route by using `HttpHost` with a resolved `InetAddress`.

Try out this code and let me know if that does the trick.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createSystem();
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(InetAddress.getByName("endpoint.com"), "another_endpoint_name.com", -1, "https");
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(host, new HttpGet("https://another_endpoint_name.com/stuff"))) {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code did not work because the IP Address is resolving the name "another_endpoint_name.com" and needs to resolve "endpoint.com". However, I could see that the Server Name Indication is set by the second parameter in the HttpHost constructor "hostname". I don't know why the IP Address is not set by InetAddress.getByName("endpoint.com") in the first parameter. Is this the correct behavior? https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpHost.html

Comment: I have a suspicion that there is a problem with your DNS configuration.

Comment: I think you're correct. I'll wait the Operations Team responsible of the host I need to connect to say what really needs to be configured. Thanks for your help!